# Lilypond: \transpose syntax for an entire song

Tags: lilypond, transposition

I am trying to transpose an entire song from B Flat Major to A Major. There is only one part for a "C" instrument. I have it tagged as "flute", but it could just as easily function with a C Melody saxophone, the melody line for a piano, etc. I have tried placing the command in my song in a number of places, but unless the syntax needs to be changed, there is only one place that I can get this to work:

```
    }

  \transpose bf a { \flute }

  \score {
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Flute"
    midiInstrument = "flute"
  } \flute
  \layout { }
  \midi {
    \tempo 4=80
  }
```

The code above the first "}" is the music score.

My problem is that the music score gets transposed, but there is also an original non-transposed score that appears below the transposed score. What am I doing wrong? I am using Frescobaldi for entering most of the code.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused with your question. `\transpose bf a { c4 d e f }` should work fine, so I'm assuming this isn't what you're looking for. Are you just trying to transpose a single line and only print that single line?

Answer (score 3):

Your example produces two scores because that's what it contains.

The first `\transpose` command is a music expression, so it creates a score with the default clef, time signature, etc.

And the `\score` creates another score, (of course!) which doesn't specify any transposition, so you don't get any.

Presumably you didn't try the option which *does* work (I turned it into a complete working input file):

```
\version "2.18.2"
\include "english.ly"

flute = \relative c'' { bf c d ef f g a bf }

\score {
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Flute"
    midiInstrument = "flute"
  }
  \transpose bf a { \flute }
  \layout { }
  \midi {
     \tempo 4=80
  }
}
```

I don't use Frescobaldi, so I don't know if that won't let you create the correct input for some reason.

Comment: Works fine on Frescobaldi for me!

Comment: Errors:

``Processing `/tmp/frescobaldi-kbdlnaun/tmpufygf22v/my_immortal.ly'
Parsing...
/tmp/frescobaldi-kbdlnaun/tmpufygf22v/my_immortal.ly:66:3: error: syntax error, unexpected MUSIC_FUNCTION
  
  \transpose bf a { \flute }
/tmp/frescobaldi-kbdlnaun/tmpufygf22v/my_immortal.ly:71:1: error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

}
fatal error: failed files: "/tmp/frescobaldi-kbdlnaun/tmpufygf22v/my_immortal.ly"
Exited with return code 1.``

Comment: The entire score is at http://lilybin.com/sj1qh2/2

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I found was the following:

```
    }

flutePart = \new Staff \with {
  instrumentName = "Flute"
  midiInstrument = "flute"
} \flute

\score {
  <<
    \transpose bf a \flutePart
  >>
  \layout { }
  \midi {
    \tempo 4=80
  }
}
```

I am not sure why that works and other solutions don't, but this solution certainly works for me with Frescobaldi.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example:

```
\score {
  <<
    \new ChordNames {
      \set chordChanges = ##t
      \transpose e c { \harmonies }
    }
    \new PianoStaff {
    <<
        \new Voice = "voice" { \transpose e c { \melody } }
        \new Lyrics \lyricsto "words" \text
        \new Voice = "accordion" { \transpose e c { \harmony } }
    >>
    }
  >>

  \layout { 
   #(layout-set-staff-size 16)
   }
  \midi { 
    \tempo 4 = 125
  }

}
```